# Passing JSON array from javascript variable to java in android

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, json

I have an array of JSON data already stored in a javascript variable as below:

```
var data = [{"a":153.15,"b":26.15,"c":item1},{"a":148.63,"b":23.45,"c":item2}];
function alertJson(data) {
    Android.alertJson(data);
}
```

Then, I would like to do in java something like this:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void alertJson(Array jsonStr) {
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String a = jsonobject.getString("a");
        String b = jsonobject.getString("b");
        String c = jsonobject.getString("c");
    }
}
```

Now I am getting an error saying Array cannot be resolved to a type at Array jsonStr.

But the problem is jsonStr is undefined or not initialized. I want to get the value(array) of the javascript variable in jsonStr so I can use it in java. How can I achieve this?

By the way, I know how to bind javascript to android. I guess I just need a way to store the array in jsonStr somehow like using a function. Please help me.

Comment: Convert the json array to string and then send.

Comment: can you show how you got jsonStr?

Comment: @TomerShemesh I just edited my question to add information. What I am trying to do is using the java code when onclick happens in webview. Can you help me further? Thank you!

Comment: @Azim Can you explain in detail? Did you mean I should change JSONArray to something else?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var data = JSON.parse('[{"a":153.15,"b":26.15,"c":item1},{"a":148.63,"b":23.45,"c":item2}]');

and

Android.alertJson(data.stringify());

public void alertJson(Array jsonStr) { // Change Array to String
```

Comment: I am getting an "Array cannot be resolved to a type" error at line "public void alertJson(Array jsonStr) {". Should I change Array at this line to something else before I try the way you suggested? Thanks.

Comment: should work.. put toast message.. in ur and try to do toast

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my problem seems to lie not in parsing the data in javascript, rather in my java code. Can you look into my java code?

Comment: Like you said, toast works great. I just also need a way to access to the data items in java :)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well. Solution:

```
var data = [{"a":153.15,"b":26.15,"c":item1},{"a":148.63,"b":23.45,"c":item2}];
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data );
Android.alertJson(myJSON);
```

On Android (Kotlin):

```
@JavascriptInterface
    fun alertJson(myJSON: String) {
       var jsonarray = JSONArray(myJSON)
       // iterate through jsonarray 
}
```

Java (not tested, but probably works)

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void alertJson(String myJSON) {
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(myJSON);
    // iterate through jsonarray 

}
```